# Sorting a list of students

Tags: python

Hi I am new to programming and I am trying to write a program that takes a list of student names and sorts them to create a class roll. The list of names will be given on a one line separated by a single space. It is in alphabetical order

This is what I want the output to looks like.
[image]

This is my current code below and I am not sure why it keeps coming up with errors.

```
names = input('Students: ')

print('Class Roll')

  output = names.sort()

print(output)
```

Comment: It would help if you could at least actually tell us what those errors are

Comment: `output = names.sort()` => `output = sorted(names.split())`. `sort` works in-place, `output` will be `None`

Comment: what errors? Please read through [mcve] so that we can help finding a solution.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specifically mention the errors you are talking about

Comment: After it says class roll it comes up with an error

Comment: Please specify the exact error message next time. If I tell you that my car doesn't start you won't be able to tell me exactly what's wrong (e.g. no fuel, no key, no electricity, ...). Same thing here. If you just tell us that there was "an error" we can't help you.

Answer (score -1):

You never split the input apart so there isn't anything to sort

```
names = names.split()
names.sort()
```

Comment: This comes up with the class roll saying none even if you type in names into the students input

Comment: @cars - Well yes... you no longer need to use the `output` variable... There is still some work needed to be done here to iterate over the names for your output but I figured that wasn't part of the core issue

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few problems I see with your code

1. The input is read as a trying, you need to split this into individual names
2. `sort` works inplace, it returns None

You can do the following

1. Modify the input command as `names = input('Students: ').split(' ')`
2. `print(names)` instead of output

**EDIT**

To print them in the manner shown in the question do

```
for name in names:
    print(name)
```

Comment: This code works but it prints them in a single line like this ['Fred', 'Bob']   If you go above to the question I have shown what I am trying to make the code look like